# How do I properly compile and link a resource file using MSVC command line toolchain?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, embedded-resource

I am a beginner to Windows API, and trying to learn how to make applications and such. I got to this part in the winprog.org articles, where the author started using resource files. I have written the resource file, in the .rc format. I compile it using the rc command, and it compiles into a .res file. Then I pass it off to the linker along with the the main object file, again, all from the command line. But when I run the linked executable, it does not show me the menu I defined in the resource file. Nor the icon I specified in there.

I am using Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio, partly to get comfortable with the MSVC CLI, and partly because I just like VSCode better. I also don't want to install additional C/C++ compilers when I already have MSVC.

So,

1. How should I go about compiling and linking the resource file correctly?
2. Are there any more up-to-date and not nightmarish methods to learn how to work with the Windows API?

Comment: Often digging up the command lines generated and used by Visual Studio for a similar VS-managed project helps. Clearly you don't want to mindlessly copy it, but it should be full of commands  and options you can look up to understand WHY Visual Studio used them. you can find the command line for a *tool* in Project-> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> *tool* -> Command Line.

Comment: *But when I run the linked executable, it does not show me the menu I defined in the resource file. Nor the icon I specified in there.* -- We have no idea what your rc file actually consists of, and how you wrote your program to access the resources.  This may have nothing to do with compiling resource files and linking, and everything to do with a buggy program or some sort of incorrect identifiers being used in the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

You compile the resource script using the [Resource Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler) (rc.exe) and pass its output on to the linker. There is no other magic involved.